# Bash exec missing terminating value

Tags: bash, find, applescript, exec, terminate

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find anything that applies to my situation but it's possible I'm not understanding where I'm making the mistake. I apologize in advance if this has been answered before I just can't seem to find where the problem is..

My code is throwing the error:

> find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set filesString to ""
    repeat with file_ in input
        set filesString to filesString & " " & quoted form of (POSIX path of file_)
    end repeat
    {}
    do script "MOVIES=/Volumes/MEDIA/Video;
find \"$MOVIES\" -name '*.mkv' -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i \"$0\" -vcodec copy -acodec copy \"${0%%.mkv}.mp4\" ' ; "

    end tell
    return input
end run
```

I'm attempting to use automator to simplify the process of conversions. Hopefully it's not too complicated of a solution.

Update: I seem to have fixed the previous issue but now it's throwing a

> sh: No such file or directory

the code below works alone in the terminal but not through automator:

```
MOVIES=/Volumes/MEDIA/Video
find "$MOVIES" -name '*.mkv' -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "${0%%.mkv}.mp4"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the `;` (double `\` because of your quotes) at the end of find

```
   do script "MOVIES=/Volumes/MEDIA/Video;
find \"$MOVIES\" -name '*.mkv' -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i \"$0\" -vcodec copy -acodec copy \"${0%%.mkv}.mp4\" ' \\; "
```

Comment: Perfect that seems to have fixed it but for some reason it's not finding the directory which does exist... the code below works alone in the terminal but not through automator:          `MOVIES=/Volumes/MEDIA/Video \n       
find "$MOVIES" -name '*.mkv' -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "${0%%.mkv}.mp4"' {} \;`

Comment: I was using google/zx and had to escape the slashes for the `sed` command: `find ./__tests__ -name "*.js" -exec sed -i "" "s/..\\/api/..\\/src\\/api/g" {} \\;`